# how to fetch facebook page status in J2SE DeskTop app

Tags: java, facebook, web

Hello I have read the facebook API for websites. And I added a facebook plugin which fetches the latest posts into a panel of the website.Now I need to send this posts into an desktop J2SE application via the website or directly from facebook. Is there any way to fetch the facebook page updates into the J2SE app ? Or is there any way to fetch the facebook updates (which is fetched from facebook) from website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook page provides `JSON` feed and I parsed the `JSON` to get that feed.

Comment: Is it possible to get the comments from facebook post in Java desktop application??